# Why are all ids being returned instead of the one matching search criteria

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm trying to learn JSON path and I'm using the sample at https://codebeautify.org/jsonpath-tester# to practice.

I'm trying to extract the id based on the employee's first name as below:

```
$.employees.employee[?(@firstName='Tom')].id
```

However it returns all the ids. How do I pick the id based on firstName?

Comment: `$.employees.employee[?(@firstName=='Tom')].id` note the `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `$.employees.employee[?(@.firstName == 'Tom')].id`

You are missing `@.firstName` and `==`